# Two completely separate versions of trac

Tags: trac

I would like to install a complete new version of Trac alongside of our current version (0.11.7) and I am looking for ways to do this.  After some research, it says to use python's virtualenv, but I am trying to find specific steps on how to accomplish this without interfering with our 0.11.7 version at all.

I am using Ubuntu as the OS.  Any input including any possible pitfalls is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) that makes using python-virtualenv a breeze.

The steps to create and use such a Python virtual environment are explained in [the user documentation](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). These environments form the core setup of my own Trac plugin development. It allows to even use custom python versions, if you ever need that. I found the need to give each environment a self-explaining name and use it with different Trac environment directories matching the db version required by different Trac versions, i.e. virtualenv "trac-0.11_py2.4" with Trac env "sandbox_0.11", "trac-0.12_py2.6" with Trac env "sandbox_0.12", etc.